# Strange cubemap shadow behavior

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to create omnidirectional shadow mapping with a cube map and a simple scene.  But I am getting very strange behavior with my shadows. Watch the GIF i created, the small ball moving across the screen is the point light position that casts the shadows.

https://giphy.com/gifs/3og0IwrSKtjmeL7iYU/fullscreen

First I set up the Cube map texture

```
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMap, cubemapID);
            for(int i = 0;i<6;i++)
            {
                GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMapPositiveX + i, 0, PixelInternalFormat.DepthComponent, 1024, 1024, 0, PixelFormat.DepthComponent, PixelType.Float, (IntPtr)null);
            }
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMap,TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMap, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Nearest);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMap, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMap, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.TextureCubeMap, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapR, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);


            Matrix4[] ShadowTransforms = new Matrix4[6];
            shadowprojection = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(90f), 1024 / 1024, 0.1f, 25f);
            ShadowTransforms[0] = shadowprojection * Matrix4.LookAt(light.Position, light.Position + new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), new Vector3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
            ShadowTransforms[1] = shadowprojection * Matrix4.LookAt(light.Position, light.Position + new Vector3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), new Vector3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
            ShadowTransforms[2] = shadowprojection * Matrix4.LookAt(light.Position, light.Position + new Vector3(0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
            ShadowTransforms[3] = shadowprojection * Matrix4.LookAt(light.Position, light.Position + new Vector3(0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
            ShadowTransforms[4] = shadowprojection * Matrix4.LookAt(light.Position, light.Position + new Vector3(0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), new Vector3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
            ShadowTransforms[5] = shadowprojection * Matrix4.LookAt(light.Position, light.Position + new Vector3(0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), new Vector3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
```

I use a special shaders to create the cube map.

Vertex Shader:

```
            #version 330 core
            layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;

            uniform mat4 CurrentTransformation;
            void main()
            {
               gl_Position = CurrentTransformation * position;
            }
```

Geometry shader:

```
        #version 330 core
        layout (triangles) in;
        layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices=18) out;

        uniform mat4 shadowMatrices[6];
        out vec4 FragPos; // FragPos from GS (output per emitvertex)

        void main()
        {
            for(int face = 0; face < 6; ++face)
            {
                gl_Layer = face; // built-in variable that specifies to which face we render.
                for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) // for each triangle's vertices
                {
                    FragPos = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
                    gl_Position = shadowMatrices[face] * FragPos;
                    EmitVertex();
                }    
                EndPrimitive();
            }
        }
```

Fragment Shader:

```
            #version 330 core
            in vec4 FragPos;
            uniform vec3 lightPos;
            uniform float far_plane;

            void main()
            {
                // get distance between fragment and light source
                float lightDistance = length(FragPos.xyz - lightPos);

                // map to [0;1] range by dividing by far_plane
                lightDistance = lightDistance / far_plane;

                // write this as modified depth
                gl_FragDepth = lightDistance;
            }
```

Then once my cubemap is created I use it to calculate shadows in the ordinary fragment shaders

```
            struct Light 
            {    
                vec3 Position;
                vec3 AttenuationFactor;
                vec3 Direction;
                vec4 Color;
                float Angle;
                int SpecularSize;
                float MinimumAmbient;
            };
            uniform Light Lights[10];

            float ShadowCalculation(Light l1)
            {
                //get vector between fragment position and light position
                vec3 fragToLight = vec3(newposition.x,newposition.y,newposition.z) - lightpos;
                // use the light to fragment vector to sample from the depth map    
                float closestDepth = texture(depthMap, fragToLight).r;
                // it is currently in linear range between [0,1]. Re-transform back to original value
                closestDepth *= far_plane;
                // now get current linear depth as the length between the fragment and light position
                float currentDepth = length(fragToLight);
                // now test for shadows
                float bias = 0.05; 
                float shadow = currentDepth -  bias > closestDepth ? 1.0 : 0.0;
                return shadow;
            }

            void main()
            {
                vec4 lightresult = vec4(0,0,0,0);
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    if(i == lightcount){break;}
                    lightresult += //Normal lighting calculations here//
                    lightresult = lightresult *=(1-ShadowCalculation(Lights[i]));
                }
                outputF = lightresult;
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?